# Can't connect to datomic on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, datomic

According to the datomic documentation, I have created a VPC and put my elastic beanstalk application in the same vpc as the datomic system. However, when I connect to the database in my server on the elastic beanstalk, I get the following error:

```
Forbidden to read keyfile at s3://humboi-march-2021-storagef7f305e7-1h3lt-s3datomic-1650q253gkqr1/humboi-march-2021/datomic/access/dbs/db/humboi-march-2021/read/.keys. Make sure that your endpoint is correct, and that your ambient AWS credentials allow you to GetObject on the keyfile.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using static programmatic access credentials, make sure the user associated with those credentials has permission to interact to the bucket where the key file is and permission to call s3:GetObject (check the policy on the user in the IAM console)
2. Make sure your bucket policy is not denying the identity tied to those credentials from calling s3:GetObject (check the bucket's bucket policy in the S3 console)
3. If the credentials are tied to the Beanstalk service role (ambient), ensure the role has permission to s3:GetObject (check the Beanstalk service role in the IAM console)
4. If the ambient credentials are inferred from an EC2 instance that was created by Beanstalk, make sure the instance role has permission to call s3:GetObject. (check the EC2 instance role in the IAM console)